# start-stop-daemon saves wrong PID

Tags: linux, debian, daemon, init.d

```
$ ps aux | grep svn
root      **4458** ... /usr/bin/svnserve -d -r /var/svn
manuel    4466 ... grep --color=auto svn
$ sudo kill **4458**
$ sudo rm /var/run/svnserve.pid
$ sudo start-stop-daemon --start --make-pidfile --pidfile /var/run/svnserve.pid --exec /usr/bin/svnserve -- -d -r /var/svn
$ cat /var/run/svnserve.pid
**4474**
$ ps aux | grep svn
root     **4477**  ... /usr/bin/svnserve -d -r /var/svn
manuel    4480     ... grep --color=auto svn
```

Why is start-stop-daemon saving wrong pids?

Comment: What is the process behind the actual PID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You used the `-d` flag in svnserve, which means that svnserve forks, and child processes will have different pids, than the parent svnserve process.

`start-stop-daemon` doesn't know about child process pids.

Suggestion:

- Use `pid-file` from svnserve to determine pid number (And remove the `make-pidfile` argument.)
- Disable forking in svnserve, and configure `start-stop-daemon` to do this as well (there is an example on the bottom of `manpage`)

Comment: But where is the svnserve.pid file?

Comment: You need to add --pid-file parameter to svnserve command, example: start-stop-daemon --start -p /var/run/svnserve.pid --exec  /usr/bin/svnserve -- -d -r /mnt/ --pid-file /var/run/svnserve.pid

Comment: Damn. Thats what I've overlooked. svnserve itself has a --pid-file option. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Probably because svnserve makes it's own pidfile.

Comment: oh do you know where this is or how i should handle this?

Comment: depends on what you exactly want it to do. You can either remove the --make-pidfile and make sure the --pidfile points to the svnserve pidfile.